# Using bootstrap and such and getting rid of unwanted css/functions

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

this may seem like a little silly question but to me its important and takes a lot of time and im thinking of theres an easier way to do it, or just how you other guys do.

Im using bootstrap from time to time cause I think their solutions is really clean and easy to implement but often you get so much more than you wanted. For an example I have a collapse menu that Im using and its very nice, but to use it I have to use 2 different CSS containing so much I dont use.

How do I in the best way reduce this if I for example dont want their css, but only the code used for this menu and copy it in my css instead. So far Im using the inspector to see what the mentioned elements have and are referred in the bootstrap css and then I trie to copy these lines into mine and update and remove the bootstrap.css to see if everythings stay the same. I come a good way to solve it but its very timeconsuimg since the bootstrap.css is so big and have many global selectors that affect the look as well. I will eventually get to the bottom of it, no doubt, but as I said it takes a long time and maybe theres an easier way?

I want to do this because I want to understand everything that is in my theme(using wordpress) and not just copy-paste and be happy with it working. I want to have a clear view of my setup for the website and I think im not getting that if I include files that I dont really know what they are doing, and they are taking up space thats not needed as well so its good for the future to be able to handle these situations many more times.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a customization page for bootstrap.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

There you can customize almost everything.

Answer (score 0):

You would possibly have to work with the source code. For example, you could modify this scss file at your end to choose what you need and build

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/bootstrap.scss

or less in previous versions
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/bootstrap.less